# Using a list method to populate a graph in C#

Tags: c#, graph

I am trying to learn how to make graphs and populate them using a data list I cal from my class. I made a method to read all my Scale values then I call it to my form. After doing research I found one that looked promising so I modified it to work for me. Upon completion I received the following errors and after looking it up I'm still not sure why. Is there a better way of filling my chart with points using a list and or how can I salvage this one. Thank you in advance.

errors:
cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPointCollection' to 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Class1'

The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List.Add(WindowsFormsApplication1.Class1)' has some invalid arguments

Method I am using:

```
 List<Class1> points = new List<Class1>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            points.Add(new DataPoint(i, 1));
        }

        points.Clear();
```

Comment: you have a list of `Class1`, you are adding a `DataPoint` to it.  It (understandably) doesn't like that

Comment: @Jonesy ok I unserstand how can I add the points directly to the graph?